# "access is denied" error when getting user input in c

Tags: c, mingw

I have installed the MinGW and added the binary folder to the path in system variables. When I just print "Hello world", It prints normally on the screen. But when I try to get user input using `scanf()` (example given below), it compiles, but when I try to run it, it says "access is denied". Can someone please help me with this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){

    int num = 0;
    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("%d", num * 2);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) ? Did you read the documentation of  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ? Did you read the documentation of `MinGW` ? Are you allowed to install [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66834548/edit) your question to explain in written English how did you run your compiler? You should try `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g hello.c -o hello.exe`

Comment: Getting "access denied" as a result of running a.exe from your Desktop implies a system configuration issue. Try compiling and running your program from a different directory that isn't your desktop folder.

Comment: On my x86-64 desktop running [Ubuntu 20.04](http://ubuntu.com/) your example compiles `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g ranuja.c -o ranuja` and runs (with `./ranuja`) as expected, so you should consider installing a better operating system on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support. I finally figured it out. It was the antivirus software blocking the execution of the code. When I uninstalled it, the code ran perfectly.